# Formula for compounding interest daily?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know the formula for finding a balance in a bank account that receives 1% interest daily. I tried this $A(t)=P(1+rn)nt$, but I don't think it is the formula I am looking for.

The interest is calculated daily, and then automatically added to the balance.

Comment: Don't you mean $P(t) = P_0\left(1 + \frac{r}{N}\right)^{Nt}$?  Note that $N$ is the number of times interest is compounded annually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balance@dayN = Balance@day1 * (1.01)^(N-1)

By the way, this is not linear algebra. Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).

Receiving 1% interest means multiplying what you have by 1.01. You multiply once every day.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for what I needed. And I wasn't quite sure what tag to use sorry. First time.

Comment: @DominicWasko, so please mark the question as answered.